# Is it possible to make only one connection to oracle DB for several SQLPLUS from Windows Batch script?

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus, windows-scripting

I developed a Windows batch script which launch several sqlplus script and specifically an sqlplus in a loop.

So, i'm asking if it is possible to make a single db connection by calling another sqlplus or whatever.

In fact, there are some performances problems by connecting and disconnecting to the database in that loop.

Here an exemple of the loop :

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 DELIMS=/ " %%a in (%USER_LOGS%) do (
    sqlplus /nolog @%SQL_CONSTRUCT_CSV% %%b %%a %PATH_CSV% %ORACLE_CONNECTSTR%
)
```

And in my sqlplus :

```
connect &4.
```

I tried to call an sqlplus at the start of bat file which is involved in making the connection with the database but it doesn't works.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't very helpful. Can you use your loop to create a temporary script that contains all your other calls, and then execute that combined script once from a single SQL\*Plus session?

Comment: "It doesn't works" means that the connection is not useful for sqlplus called. In this sqlplus i construct a .CSV file for each line found in "USER LOG" file. (More precisely, for each user found in that file, i make a query). And i cannot acces to this file from my DB server.